# Does Naruto only have the wind chakra nature?

Tags: naruto

Does Naruto have only the wind chakra nature?

If he doesn't then why doesn't he use any different chakra nature besides the Rasen Shuriken?

Comment: He apparently has wind, lightning, earth, fire, water, lava, magnet, boil, yin, yang, and yin-yang as his nature types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont read manga. But I watched anime till the latest episode. But he still only used wind chakra. Does he use other chakra nature in manga?

Comment: He uses all of them in the anime and in the manga. In his Rasengans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in the comment section, Naruto "apparently has wind, lightning, earth, fire, water, lava, magnet, boil, yin, yang, and yin-yang as his nature types". Which you can see [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki).

In the comment section you said you watched the anime till the end. But, even so, you should have still seen him use the other chakra natures. It was during the war, I don't remember exacly what episode(s) but in the manga it showed in chapter 673: WE Will...!! (in this chapter he uses *Sage Art! **Lava Style** Rasen Shuriken!*). In the next chapter, Sasuke's Rinnegan, he uses *Sage Art! **Magnet Style** Rasengan*.

In Chapter 688: He of the Sharingan!!, the Biju give Naruto part of their chakra which he uses for *Sage Art...... Super Bijuu Rasen Shuriken!!*. But the manga doesn't say what the other seven Shuriken are made of.

[Yin Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yin_Release):

> - based on the spiritual energy that governs imagination, can be used to create form out of nothingness.
> - According to the Second Mizukage's, genjutsu falls under the broad category of Yin Release.
> - Yin chakra is also part of the tailed beasts' chakra.
> - Yin Release can be used offensively when combined with senjutsu. However, it is unknown what exact role the Yin Release fulfils in said technique.

I'm pretty sure statement three is the reason why Naruto has Yin release. My theory behind this is (could be canon)

> During the war, if you remember, Naruto died. Which lead to Minato sealing the Yin half into Naruto.

I think that's the reason for him having Yin Release, but, remember, I could be totally wrong.

[Yang Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yang_Release):

> - based on the physical energy that governs vitality, can be used to breathe life into form.
> - Yang chakra is also part of the tailed beasts' chakra.

This second statement is, what I think, the reason behind Naruto having Yang Release.

> Minato had sealed the Yang half of Kurama in Naruto. Making him gian Yang Release. So when ever Naruto is is Nine-Tails Chakra Mode, Tensou's wood style would have a reactions towards the Yang chakra.

[Yin-Yang Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yin%E2%80%93Yang_Release) is just the, what someone can call, "combination" of Yin and Yang Release.

> - After receiving power from Hagoromo, Naruto Uzumaki gained the ability to use Yin–Yang Release to stabilise life forces and restore missing organs through physical contact.

Like how he healed Gui after his fight with Madara. But, it seems to have a limit. For example, it was unable to fix Gui's leg after he used Night Guy. Another example is how Naruto was able to heal Obito from the Ten-Tails extraction, but wasn't able to heal him from Kaguya's *All-Killing Ash Bones*

> - Yin–Yang Release also has the ability to nullify the effects of all ninjutsu, rendering them useless.

---

*Sorry for making my answer pretty long. I tried to make it as short and detailed as possible. I hope this more detailed answer helps you understand more.*

Comment: he also replaces kakashi's eye just by touching him

Answer (score 1):

Wind is the nature his chakra naturally leans towards. Most peoples Chakra is most easily converted into one specific nature, and in Naurto's case, it was wind. He then used clones to effectively spend years worth of time to use wind chakra and then add it to his rasengan.

Kakashi noted that while you may naturally be more easily able to use your specific nature, you are not limited to just that one nature. Sasuke for instance is a Fire nature, but also learned the Lightning Nature Chidori. Kakashi was able to use his natural skill and Sharingan to copy any primary nature, and though the use of those copied techniques, can use all 5 primary natures.

Naruto was special though, because he is generally really bad at learning. Outside of using hundreds of clones, he can't learn new techniques without years of work. Once he learned how to modify the rasengan in a few different ways (Big rasengan, Rasenshuriken) he was able to extend that to the other rasengan based techniques he used, like Mini Rasenshuriken.

As noted in the comments though, Naruto gained access to all of the Primary natures, Yin, Yang, and Yin-Yang, as well as several Kekei Genkai Combination Natures. This was thanks to 2 things, First, his borderline 10 tails Jinchuriki host status, and the Senjutsu of the Sage of Six Paths. When he was given the Senjutsu of the SOSP, he gained full access to the natures of all 9 tailed beasts which were inside of him, and more from the Senjutsu itself. He is now able to create Rasengan of any nature the 9 tailed beasts can use, and the Senjutsu gave him access to Yin-Yang release (which he used to give Kakashi a new eye).

So, in that regard, he does have access to over 10 natures, including several Kekei Genkai Natures, but he can only use them to convert the nature of Rasengan. Why that is, we can only speculate. He used his clones to spend effectively years of time mastering how to convert the nature of the Rasengan using Wind chakra, so it theoretically should be pretty easy for him to do the same thing with other natures he gained access to. But, he has not spent any time learning new techniques. By the time the war started, he only had Rasenshuriken, so at least until the complete end of the war and release of the Infinite Tsukuyomi, him using any other techniques not directly derived from rasengan would be plot holes. He had no time to learn how to do anything besides Rasengan and Nature manipulated Rasengan. After that, Its just his Bad learning Status, he simply never spent the time to learn how to do other techniques besides the rasengan.

Now, Theoretically, he could do so. Having Kurama's Cooperation, he could probably create a thousand clones and train for a few days, and there by learn new techniques, but as far as we know as of writing this, he doesn't. Why he doesn't is anyones guess, but its probably because he doesn't need to. He is already tied for first place with Sasuke as the strongest, and since they are friends and far ahead of everyone else, there is no one to make him train. Even when someone does come along like that, its over too fast or he is already strong enough they weren't a threat.

Comment: Kakashi and Sasuke both possess Lightning Nature Chakra. Being an Uchiha he learnt Fire Release because generally Uchiha have Fire Affinity. Also afaik Kakashi has never used Wind Style Chakra Manipulation. He has been seen using the other four though

Comment: Also, Sasuke's nature is Lightning, which was proven by Kakashi by having Sasuke holding a chakra testing paper. It makes the same wrinkles just like if Kakashi is holding it.

Comment: @AyaseEri and Arcane. I can agree, looking back, I dont see Kakashi ever using Wind style, though i dont recall claiming that either. The Wiki does claim he can though. Wiki also says Sasuke's Lighting style affinity is Anime only. The WIki later on says he has an affinity for both fire and lightning, so it looks like Manga wise he has both, but not a kekei genkai combo of them (though maybe blaze release counts).

Comment: Even in Manga Sasuke has both Lightning and Fire affinity. The wiki must be in the wrong

Comment: @絢瀬絵里 Is it really an affinity, or like Kakashi did he just learn how to do it. If it was described as an affinity, then can you provide a source chapter at least?

Answer (score 0):

I never noticed him using any jutsu using any other chakra nature. But in the latest Boruto chapter he is shown using earth style (mud wall), to block Boruto's water style attack when they were sparring. And he is the Hokage so it seems he would have picked up a few jutsu along the way.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]! Could you specify the latest chapter number instead of only mentioning "the latest Boruto chapter"? In 3 months, "the latest Boruto chapter" won't probably show him using the mentioned attack.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the answer, straight up. Naruto's only chakra nature is NOT Wind Release.**

First off, Naruto has Kekkei Genkai, Boil Release, Magnet Release, and Lava Release. Kekkei Genkai are stated to be inherited powers, such as Kimimaro's bone manipulation, or two chakra natures being mixed, for example, Wood Release is the mixture of Earth and Water. Naruto's three Kekkei Genkai obviously aren't hereditary as nor Minato or Kushina has these natures.

Once Naruto awakened Rikudou Senjutsu, along with the chakra given to him by all nine Tailed Beast (bijuu) he gained access to the five basic chakra natures, Fire, Wind Earth, Lightning, and water, and also gained the Kekkei Genkai of the Bijuu, Boil Release, Magnet Release, and Lava Release.