# Why didn't Naruto's Rasengan beat Sasuke's Chidori?

Tags: naruto

According to Kakashi, there are 5 fundamental chakra natures: fire, wind, lightning, earth, and water. Each nature is superior than another, and inferior to a different one.

[image: 5 fundamental chakra]

Focusing on wind and lightning chakras, Naruto's only nature chakra is wind, so the Rasengan must be a wind-type jutsu. Chidori, of course, is lighting. Kakashi said to Naruto that, using wind chakra, he cannot defeat Sasuke's fire abilities, but against lightning, wind can easily beat his lightning jutsus.

This leads me to my question...

[image: battle between Naruto and Sasuke]

In the *Naruto* series, there are many occurrences where Naruto clashes with Sasuke. Their battles always end with a Rasengan against Chidori blast.

Since Rasengan is generally wind-type and Chidori is lightning, shouldn't Rasengan easily beat Chidori? I can't imagine how a lighting style jutsu can match, even beat a wind-style jutsus. Maybe Kishimoto accidentally forgot about wind's superiority over lightning, but I just want to ask: can someone explain?

Comment: Rasengan does not have any nature associated with it and Naruto was able to use it long before he could control the nature of chakra

Comment: You make several assumptions in your question, some of them completely wrong. Some additional reading. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39068/does-naruto-only-have-the-wind-chakra-nature/39076#39076 http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/what-are-the-types-of-jutsus-that-exist-in-naruto/3043#3043

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard Rasengan [has no natures associated with it.](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rasengan)  It was originally based on the Tailed Beast Ball, which is simply a ***dense*** amount of chakra directed at a target.

Eventually, Naruto adds his wind nature to Rasengan, which, [in turn](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Release:_Rasengan), [creates several](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Release:_Rasenshuriken) different variations of it.  But neither of these variations are being discussed.

[image]

However, this doesn't mean that either Chidori or Rasengan have a direct type-advantage over the other.  At that point, it becomes a matter of the abilities and strengths of the wielder, and as we now understand it...

> ...it ended in what could be seen as a draw, with both Naruto and Sasuke losing the arms in which they perform the jutsu for their final fight.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense Jiraiya said that rasengan was stronger then Chidori.

Comment: Just because a type is _generally_ inferior or superior does not mean that it will always lose or win.

Comment: @qowmeq Water typically puts out a fire.  However a spray bottle of water won't do anything to a raging forest fire.  Just because the Rasengan may be "stronger" than Chidori with a given set of parameters (same amount of chakra used, skill of the ninja, etc) doesn't mean that an exceptionally skilled ninja with a very strong Chidori couldn't beat an average Rasengan.

Comment: Then if Rasengan is just a condensed form of targeted chakra and Chidori is a much advanced form of Rasengan, Why didn't chidori win over Rasengan everytime?

Comment: I think I remember Kakashi explaining Naruto that, Rasengan is the peak of Shape manipulation and Chidori is the peak of Nature manipulation so each one is stronger in their own respect and they didn't end with one winning over the other. Is this correct?

Answer (score -1):

As we know sasuke had the intent to kill, on the contrary Naruto was there to get sasuke back rather then killing him there with a full-fledged chidori

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. This site is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. As of current writing, your answer lacks of references and looks like a persona theory. We generally accept personal theory if it's well backed up by some references. You can still [edit] your post to improve it.